# What is the preferred template control to handle unassigned variables in PHPBB3?

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm trying to handle a control case where a variable is not defined.

This is what seems to work, but is also ugly.  Any ways to make this work better?

```
<!-- IF UNASSIGNED_VARIABLE -->
<!-- ELSE -->
  <insert code here>
<!-- END -->
```

I tried a few different negation structures, but they only worked when the template variable was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Common operators are [described on the wiki](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Template_syntax)

```
<!-- IF not UNASSIGNED_VARIABLE -->
    <insert code here>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: It looks like the 'not' operator is an alias for '!', which I tried.  I will try and see if 'not' behaves differently.

Comment: Does it behave differently?

Comment: They are in fact aliases, and behave the same.